# Dehydrate a tastypie class with data from a related resource?

Tags: django, tastypie

I am creating an API with tasstypie and I want to retreive a user nick in a comment resource. The comment resource send the user_uri, but I can't dehydrate the info to add also the name of the user.

The models are:

```
class User(models.Model):
    nick = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 511)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments')
```

The tastypie api is:

```
class CommentResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user')


class Meta:
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'comment'
    serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
    allowed_methods = ['get']
    always_return_data=True

def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['nick_user'] = #here I want to send user nick
    return bundle
```

this get the uri from the UserResource in a 'user' variable.
How I can access to the user nick from the dehydrate method from CommentResource?

Thanks

Comment: I solve the problem. The solution is set full=True in ToOneFiel method. This return all the info of the UserResource and not only the URI.

Comment: You could also use bundle.obj.user.nick I guess.

Comment: And you could add a proper answer so that the question doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Why instead of touching the whole dehydrate method you don't use dehydrate_user(self, bundle) and return bundle.obj.nick?

Comment: Thank !! It's a good idea but I solve the problem with  'user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user', full=True)'. At this solution I have all the info of the user, and not only the nick.